# Image Angular create dynamically in assets folder refresh webpage

Tags: angular

I have an Angular webpage where I have images. I also have a script which create and save png images in assets folder. So, I want to display each image which are created dynamically in my webpage.
But when they are created, the webpage is always refreshing and this is not what I want.

Can you please, help me on how to add images in angular webpage dynamically without refreshing the page.

Comment: I guess that's because of hot reloading whenever you make changes to the project.

Comment: And are there any possibilities to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my problem.
Indeed, I just have to run my angular project with

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```

With this command, the project doesn't refresh automatically. Hope it will help other people who are facing the same issue.